# Using variable value with R.array

Tags: android, xml

I have an activity with list view. On click of an item of the list view an intent is send to the next list containing the value of the clicked item. The list is being generated using an xml file.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Selected item
    String cat  = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

    // Launching new Activity on selecting single Item List
    Intent intent   = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentListing.class);

    // Sending data to new activity
    intent.putExtra("cat", cat);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

On the next activity I again have to read an xml file but this file will vary with respect to the item clicked on previous list.

```
// Creating a handle to capture data sent from previous activity
Intent intent = getIntent();

// Storing the category into a variable
String cat = intent.getStringExtra("cat");

// Storing string resources into Array
String[] itemList   = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemList);
```

I wanted to do something like **`String[] itemList  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat);`** i.e. **R.array.variable** which doesn't work for me. I am new to java and android so any kind of help(that is easy to understand and implement) is welcome.

Also, I wanted the name of this second activity to be different each time with respect to the item clicked. What should I be doing for this?

**EDIT:**

This is my updated code which give the error about getContext()

```
    public class ContentListing extends ListActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_listing);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        }

        // Creating a handle to capture data sent from previous activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Storing the category into a variable
        String cat = intent.getStringExtra("cat");

        setTitle(cat);

        // Line that shows error
        int resourceId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(cat, "array", getContext().getPackageName());

        Log.d("Print message1: ", String.valueOf(resourceId)+"\n");
        if(resourceId != 0) {
            Log.d("Print message: ", String.valueOf(resourceId)+"\n");

            // Storing string resources into Array
            //String[] itemList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemList);
            String[] itemList   = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);

            // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item2, R.id.label, itemList));

            ListView lv = getListView();

            // Listening to single list item on click
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // Selected item
                    String product  = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                    // Launching new Activity on selecting single Item List
                    Intent intent   = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentListing.class);

                    // Sending data to new activity
                    intent.putExtra("product", product);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_content_listing, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could store all the values in the one XML file, then parse the required category from the XML hierarchy.

Comment: That seems to be a good advice. But even though I would have to write something `R.array.category` to get the category values, wouldn't I?

Comment: You would use an XML parser to pull the values from your `R.`esource. You would have to structure your XML in a categorical hierarchy.

Comment: Please don't do that.  It makes no sense, and Android already has methods for getting what you want.  Don't try to go around Android's system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to load the arrays from resources like this:

```
int resourceId=Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(cat, "array", getContext().getPackageName());
if(resourceId != 0){
  getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
}
```

To set the title of the activity,

```
setTitle(cat);
```

I would consider instead though, checking the value of the extra you passed in, then having a if else statement that loads the resource.  You have a better guarantee that things will work correctly.

```
int resId = R.array.defaultValue;
if(cat.equals("category1"){
  resId = R.array.categoryOneValues;
} else if(cat.equals("category2"){
  resId = R.array.categoryTwoValues;
}
getResources().getStringArray(resId);
```

Comment: Your first method gives me an error `The method getContext() is undefined for the type ContentListing` and second might be too lengthy. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Both approaches assume you are in an activity, or have access to a Context object.

You must have a context object to get resources anyway.  Just replace that getContext() with whatever your context is.